# Installing the open tool chain template in Xcode 4.3 or 4.4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, jailbreak

Is it possible to install the open tool chain template in Xcode 4.3 or 4.4 to do some jailbreak dev? Everything that I find seems to be a little bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've already figured this out,

Anyway, Xcode 4 onwards you do not need this plug in, you can simply create a view based application / empty application with a short and simple .plist edit to make your app work as a daemon and not as a "view based application"

Here is the relevant .plist edit http://chrisalvares.com/blog/38/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-4/

its the last part of a tutorial written in 2009, but it still applies  . . .

Hope this helps 
Taski

Comment: Hello @Taskinul , you mean in we dont have to install this open tool chain template in xocde 4.6 too?